latex on Arch Linux can't see packages installed via tlmgr
I've freshly installed texlive on Arch linux and tried to make it work using VS Code LaTeX Workshop. Unfortunatelly, when building (in VS Code or in CMD with latexmk command), I get this error:

LaTeX Error: File `systeme.sty' not found.

On the other hand, when running tlmgr install systeme, I recieve this message:

tlmgr install: package already present: systeme

The same error goes for many more packages, such as A4wide for example.
My settings.json file looks like this:
{
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "command": "latexmk",
        "args": [
            "--shell-escape", // added arg to default
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "-pdf",
            "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",////
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "xelatex",
        "command": "xelatex",
        "args": [
         "-synctex=1",
         "-interaction=nonstopmode",
         "-file-line-error",
         "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "pdflatex",
        "command": "pdflatex",
        "args": [
            "--shell-escape", // added arg to default
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "bibtex",
        "command": "bibtex",
        "args": [
            "%DOCFILE%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "tectonic",
        "command": "tectonic",
        "args": ["-X", "build", "--keep-intermediates", "--keep-logs"],
        "env": {}
      }
],
    "latex-workshop.latex.clean.command",
    "latex-workshop.latex.external.build.command"
],
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.pdf": "latex-workshop-pdf-hook"
},
"settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": [
    "james-yu.latex-workshop"
],
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [

    {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "tools": [
            "latexmk"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "latexmk (latexmkrc)",
        "tools": [
            "latexmk_rconly"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "latexmk (lualatex)",
        "tools": [
            "lualatexmk"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "latexmk (xelatex)",
        "tools": [
            "xelatexmk"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex * 2",
        "tools": [
            "pdflatex",
            "bibtex",
            "pdflatex",
            "pdflatex"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Compile Rnw files",
        "tools": [
            "rnw2tex",
            "latexmk"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Compile Jnw files",
        "tools": [
            "jnw2tex",
            "latexmk"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Compile Pnw files",
        "tools": [
            "pnw2tex",
            "latexmk"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "tectonic",
        "tools": ["tectonic"]
    }
],
"latex-workshop.latex.clean.command": "",
// "latex-workshop.latex.clean.command": "",
// "latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "tectonic",
// "latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "onSave",
// "latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "%WORKSPACE_FOLDER%/build/index",
// "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
// "latex-workshop.intellisense.biblatexJSON.replace": {
    
// },
// "latex-workshop.latex.rootFile.indicator": "\\begin{document}",
}

How can I fix this?
Edit: Minimal example to reproduce error:
main.tex:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Until here the build works fine
\usepackage{a4wide} % Here it gives error (a4wide or systeme or babel ...)

\begin{document}
    Text
\end{document}

main.log:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.6.1)  1 JUN 2024 19:58
entering extended mode
\write18 enabled.
file:line:error style messages enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**"/run/media/misa/Samsung 
USB/CVUT/AŘ/TEXtest/main.tex"
(/run/media/misa/Samsung USB/CVUT/AŘ/TEXtest/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document 
class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks17
\inpenc@posthook=\toks18
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks19
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
 (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen141
\Gin@req@width=\dimen142
)

! LaTeX Error: File `a4wide.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
/run/media/misa/Samsung USB/CVUT/AŘ/TEXtest/main.tex:6: Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.6 ^^M
       
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 707 strings out of 476042
 10082 string characters out of 5792599
 1925187 words of memory out of 5000000
 22885 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 24 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 57i,0n,65p,247b,36s stack positions out of     10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
/run/media/misa/Samsung USB/CVUT/AŘ/TEXtest/main.tex:6:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


Does kpsewhich systeme.sty find the file? If not, maybe the package is broken. Try reinstall the package using tlmgr install --reinstall systeme. But this makes only sense, if you are using the current Vanilla TeX Live release. If you use linux texlive packages, you have to install the linux package, that provides the file.

@cabohah It doesn't give any output, but shows error sign. It seems, that the same problem goes for more packages, as I dive deeper to it. For example A4wide. It seems like latexmk doesn't see the tlmgr packages.

Welcome! While debugging, compile on the command line - not in VS - and execute the command directly - not using latexmk - to simplify things. What does kpsewhich article.cls return? What does which <name-of-compilation-command-you're-using> return? Which texlive package did you install?

@cfr Excuse me, I am only used to latexmk. Which command do you recommend?

What does which tlmgr give? I'm guessing you have two TLs installed - one vanilla from upstream and Arch's.

@cfr $ which tlmgr --> /usr/bin/tlmgr

It depends on the document. Look in the log file. It will tell you which command latexmk uses right at the top of the file. Probably one of pdflatex, lualatex and xelatex.

@cfr It is pdflatex. When running that in cli it indicates many undefined control sequences (basically each line), but those are correctly written, because the build was ok on Windows (using MikTex).

What's the first error? After one error, more errors are expected. Until you address the first, the rest are generally irrelevant.

@cfr To answer your questions: The kpsewhich article.cls returns /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls. The which pdflatex returns /usr/bin/pdflatex. The first error is Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[twoside, 10pt]{article}

In that case, make a minimal example which reproduces the problem and post the code for that example and the log file. Your example should be very short, if it says \documentclass is undefined or something in the class.

@cfr I have put it to the original post.

You are using the arch linux texlive not vanilla texlive. So AFAIK tlmgr cannot install or update packages for it. Have installed all arch linux texlive packages or only some? If you have installed only some, please install all. If you have also installed a vanilla texlive, it seems it is not in PATH.

@cabohah Wouldn't be better to uninstall all arch packages and install vanilla, so that it works with tlmgr? If I understand it correctly... Or on the other hand how can I install packages for arch texlive?

Probably your PATH variable is not set properly to use the TL install although I don't know which environment VS inherits.

@user691586 This is extremely improbable given the user is using Arch's TL and not vanilla.

@ms4rkl Whether to install vanilla from upstream or Arch's packaged TL is up to you. Upstream is better for me, but it may or may not be better for you. If you're happy with Arch's packaging and you don't want the ability to switch back to a previous version, for example, and you don't mind its being installed by root, there's no particular virtue in upstream's. You don't really need tlmgr because  you have pacman (which is better at managing packages by far).

I managed to solve the problem. Big thanks to everyone who contributed to the solution in the comments.
The problem was, I had only some texlive-* packages installed on my arch system. It was solved by installing every texlive-* package available (except for the languages).
That seems to solve my problem for now.

Although you've solved the problem, this may be a candidate for closing the question. Or you might edit the title to say :Arch Linux" since it's very specific.
